# Como faço para não repetir o valor de uma celula html

Tags: c#, html, tabela-html

Como faço para não repetir o valor de uma célula em um table html ?
Por exemplo eu não quero repetir a o valor da célula `**DataPedido**`

A consulta que me retornará os dados é essa:

```
var _listaPedido = from _pedido in _pedidoAuxiliar
                                   join itens in _itemPedidoRepositorio.ListarItensPedido() on _pedido.PedidoID equals itens.PedidoID into subItemPedido
                                   from _itemPedido in subItemPedido.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   join produtos in _produtoRepositorio.ListarProduto() on _itemPedido.ProdutoID equals produtos.ProdutoID into subProduto
                                   from _produto in subProduto.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   join paes in _paoRepositorio.ListarPaes() on _produto.PaoID equals paes.PaoID into subPao
                                   from _pao in subPao.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   join fermentacao in _fermentacaoRepositorio.ListarFermentacao() on _produto.FermentacaoID equals fermentacao.FermentacaoID
                                   orderby _pedido.DataPedido
                                   where _pedido.StatusPedidoID != 5
                                   group _itemPedido by new RelVendaQtdeProduto
                                   {
                                       PedidoID = _pedido.PedidoID,
                                       PaoID = _produto.PaoID,
                                       DataPedido = _pedido.DataPedido,
                                       NomePao = _pao.NomePao,
                                       NomeFermentacao = fermentacao.NomeFermentacao,
                                       QtdeTotal = _itemPedido.QtdItem
                                   } into grupoPedido

                                   select new RelVendaQtdeProduto
                                   {
                                       PedidoID = grupoPedido.Key.PedidoID,
                                       PaoID = grupoPedido.Key.PaoID,
                                       DataPedido = grupoPedido.Key.DataPedido,
                                       NomePao = grupoPedido.Key.NomePao,
                                       NomeFermentacao = grupoPedido.Key.NomeFermentacao,
                                       QtdeTotal = grupoPedido.Sum(i => i.QtdItem)
                                   };
```

**Modelo**

```
public class Modelo
    {
        public DateTime? DataPedido { get; set; }
        public string Pao { get; set; }
        public string Fermentacao { get; set; }
        public int QtdeTotal { get; set; }
        public decimal ValorTotal { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Modelo> Modelos { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Relatorio()
        {
            IEnumerable<Modelo> pedidos = new List<Modelo>{
                new Modelo{DataPedido=Convert.ToDateTime("2016-11-29 12:24:53.707"), Pao="PÃO CONGELADO"   , Fermentacao="F"               ,QtdeTotal=5   ,ValorTotal=decimal.Parse("105.00")},
                new Modelo{DataPedido=Convert.ToDateTime("2016-11-29 12:24:53.707"), Pao="PÃO DE LEITE"    , Fermentacao="S/ Fermentação"  ,QtdeTotal=2   ,ValorTotal=decimal.Parse("16.20")},
                new Modelo{DataPedido=Convert.ToDateTime("2016-11-29 12:24:53.707"), Pao="PÃO CONGELADO"   , Fermentacao="F"               ,QtdeTotal=15  ,ValorTotal=decimal.Parse("330.00")},
                new Modelo{DataPedido=Convert.ToDateTime("2016-11-30 07:30:12.480"), Pao="PÃO COCO FRESCO" , Fermentacao="S/ Fermentação"  ,QtdeTotal=1   ,ValorTotal=decimal.Parse("10.50")},
                new Modelo{DataPedido=Convert.ToDateTime("2016-11-30 07:30:12.480"), Pao="PÃO CONGELADO"   , Fermentacao="C"               ,QtdeTotal=8   ,ValorTotal=decimal.Parse("168.00")},
                new Modelo{DataPedido=Convert.ToDateTime("2016-11-30 07:30:12.480"), Pao="PÃO CONGELADO"   , Fermentacao="L"               ,QtdeTotal=2   ,ValorTotal=decimal.Parse("42.00")},
                new Modelo{DataPedido=Convert.ToDateTime("2016-12-01 06:39:53.477"), Pao="PÃO ASSADO"      , Fermentacao="S/ Fermentação"  ,QtdeTotal=175 ,ValorTotal=decimal.Parse("38.50")},
                new Modelo{DataPedido=Convert.ToDateTime("2016-12-01 06:39:53.477"), Pao="PÃO DE LEITE"    , Fermentacao="S/ Fermentação"  ,QtdeTotal=2   ,ValorTotal=decimal.Parse("16.20")},
                new Modelo{DataPedido=Convert.ToDateTime("2016-12-01 06:39:53.477"), Pao="PÃO DE ASSADO"   , Fermentacao="S/ Fermentação"  ,QtdeTotal=35  ,ValorTotal=decimal.Parse("8.75")}
            };    
            var _pedido = pedidos.ToList();    
            return View(_pedido);
        }
```

**View**

```
<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="aling-center">DATA PEDIDO&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>PAO&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>FERMENTAÇÃO&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>QTDE&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>VALOR&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="fonte10">
                @{
                    foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item.DataPedido&nbsp;</td>                            
                            <td>@item.Pao&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>@item.Fermentacao&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>@item.QtdeTotal&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>@item.ValorTotal&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }

            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="10" class="bold"></td>
                    <td class="aling-right"></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse relatório é fixo dessa forma? Se não, você precisa colocar exatamente como é gerado essas informações, ou, caso queira fazer esse tratamento via `js` você também tem que especificar. Como quer tratar isso exatamente?

Comment: Não é fixo não coloquei dessa forma como exemplo, existe uma tela de **FILTRO** onde o usuário vai informar um período de data **INICIAL** e **FINAL**.

Comment: ou seja, você faz uma consulta a banco?

Comment: Você quer tratar na consulta ou no resultado final do `html`?

Comment: Outra pergunta, que linguagem é essa?

Comment: A consulta é feita no BD Sql Server e se possível tratar na consulta acho melhor e a linguagem é MVC.

Comment: MVC não é uma linguagem, é um padrão de arquitetura, isso que está utilizando é C3, .NET...? Não conheço muito sobre essas linguagens.

Comment: De qualquer forma, garanto que se quer tratar na consulta você precisa postar como está fazendo, e não um exemplo fixo...

Comment: Sim Csharp dot.net

Comment: Ok, então poste o código que faz a consulta!

Comment: Coloquei os dados fixos para ficar mais fácil o entendimento, de qualquer forma atualizei a pergunta adicionando a consulta, se for complicado pode dar a solução via html também.

Comment: A solução via `javascript` é simples, mas o ideal é vc tratar na consulta mesmo...estou fazendo algumas pesquisas...

Answer (score 0):

No `loop` de exibição, você pode alimentar um `array` e verificar se o valor ja foi exibido antes:

```
@{
    List<String> used = new List<String>;

    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @if(Array.IndexOf(used, item.DataPedido) < 0) {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.DataPedido&nbsp;</td>                            
                <td>@item.Pao&nbsp;</td>
                <td>@item.Fermentacao&nbsp;</td>
                <td>@item.QtdeTotal&nbsp;</td>
                <td>@item.ValorTotal&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        }

        @used.add(item.DataPedido);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como esta é uma necessidade da interface ("Como faço para não repetir o valor de uma célula em um table html?") então nem a classe Modelo nem a classe Controller deveriam ser modificadas para atender esse necessidade, de preferência apenas a View.

Utilize o atributo `rowspan=quantidade de linhas` da tag `td` computando inicialmente a quantidade de linhas a "pular" num loop anterior. Para uma melhor manutenibilidade, crie uma classe View específica que compute essa quantidade de linhas e gere o código HTML correspondente.